# Border color change on span/button hover

Tags: html, css, button, border

I have a button that has a span class within it. The span class (floated left) needs to have a border right of the '+' icon.

The issue that I'm coming across is that when i hover over the button, the span border color doesn't change from green to red (which is what i'm after).

Please see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bAv7C/9/

It doesn't seem to be reading:

```
.plus:hover{
  border-right: 2px solid red; 
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply the style to `button:hover .plus` instead. I've [forked you fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LeonardChallis/TrsYG/1/).

Comment: Hero, thank's i've been splitting ends trying to solve this :)